# Не понимаю в чем проблема в моем коде. Компилируется,но выдает ошибку stackoverflow

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
using System;

namespace cars
{
    public class Time
    {
        public int time { get; set; }
        public int timeSec(int second)
        {
            var seconds = new System.Timers.Timer(second * 1000);
            time = second;
            return time;
        }
    }
    public class Quad
    {
        public Quad() { }

        public Quad(int aRange)
        {
            a = aRange;
        }

        protected static int a;
        protected static int b
        {
            get
            {
                return a;
            }
            set
            {
                b = a;
            }
        }

        public int coordinateA;
        public int coordinateB;
        int area = a * b;

        public int GetArea()
        {
            return area;
        }
    }

    public class Map : Quad
    {
        public Map() { }

        public Map(int Range)
        {
            a = Range;
            b = a;
        }
    }
    public class car
    {
        Time timer = new Time();
        Random rand = new Random();

        public string name { get; set; }
        public int maxSpeed { get; }
        public int speed { get; set; }
        public bool isBroken
        {
            get
            {
                return isBroken;
            }
            set
            {
                if (durability >= 100)
                    isBroken = true;
            }
        }

        public double durability { get; set; }
        public bool isRiding { get; set; }
        public static int aCoord, bCoord;

        public void place(int aCoordinate, int bCoordinate)
        {
            aCoord = aCoordinate;
            bCoord = bCoordinate;
        }
        public int range = aCoord + bCoord;
        public car() { }
        public int sec;
        public car(string carName, int MaxCarSpeed, int carSpeed)
        {
            name = carName;
            maxSpeed = MaxCarSpeed;
            speed = carSpeed;
        }

        public void riding(int speed,bool isRiding,int second)
        {
            if (!isBroken)
            {
                if (speed <= maxSpeed)
                {
                    sec = second;
                    this.isRiding = true;
                    if (speed > 0 && speed < 100)
                    {
                        durability += timer.timeSec(sec) * speed / 500;
                    }
                    else if (speed > 100)
                    {
                        durability += timer.timeSec(sec) * speed / 350;
                    }
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception("you cant ride so fast");
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("car has broken");
                timer.timeSec(sec + 1);
                this.isRiding = false;
        }
        public void move(int a, int b)
        {
            if (a + b == range)
            {
                aCoord = a;
                bCoord = b;
            }
            else
            {
                aCoord = rand.Next(0, range);
                bCoord = range - aCoord;
            }
            place(aCoord, bCoord);
        }
        public void ShowCoord()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("a:" + aCoord + "\nb:" + bCoord);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            car car = new car();
            Map quadrat = new Map(500);
            Console.WriteLine(quadrat.GetArea());
            car.move(7,100);
            car.ShowCoord();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В описание вашего кода? Где оно?! Что же мы должны искать, м?

Comment: Проблема в том,что ошибок компилятор не показал,и скомпилировал.ток при этом дотнет завершает свою работу и в консоли пишет stack overflow

Comment: Исправьте свойство `isBroken` - оно ссылается само на себя в геттере и сеттере, отсюда ошибка переполнения стека. Да, и если бы вы придерживались рекомендаций по именованию свойств и полей, то вероятность появления такой ошибки была бы минимальной.

Comment: Если вы @Dan вдруг не поняли, то это строка 74 "isBroken = true;"